# Is it possible to integrate django-taggit and django-mptt / django-treebeard?

Tags: django, integration, tagging, django-mptt, django-treebeard

I am developing a website that requires tagging up different types of content, which favors using django-taggit. But, it would be extremely beneficial if the tags were represented in the database in their natural hierarchy, favoring use of django-mptt or django-treebeard.

What is the best solution to integrate the generic tagging functionality of taggit with the tree-structure provided by mptt / treebeard?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32861475/232794) might be of interest if you want duplicate nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used [treebeard and taggit's custom through models](http://tentacles666.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/django-hierarchical-tags-with-taggit-and-tree/) to implement hierarchical tags.

Comment: Cool, I actually ended up doing the same thing. Thanks for making that great how-to blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this yesterday, so I can't really tell if it's what you're looking for:

[django-categories](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-categories)

*A way to handle one or more hierarchical category trees in django.*

Comment: This looks promising, thank you. No django-taggit integration, but it sounds like it's specifically designed to allow multiple apps to efficiently use the same MPTT hierarchies. I will try this out and report back.