# Django-taggit with Django-treebeard or suitable Taxonomy app

Tags: django, tags, taxonomy, django-taggit, django-treebeard

**Environment:**
Python 2.7.10
Django 1.11.3

**Problem**
I need a Taxonomy system instead of just tags. For example:

- Art > Digital Illustration
- Programming > Websites > Code Fights
- Programming > Websites > Hackerrank
- Programming > Websites > Code Fights > Arcade > Level One
- Programming > Code Challenges

Looking around I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000457/is-it-possible-to-integrate-django-taggit-and-django-mptt-django-treebeard) in StackOverflow which led me to this [blog post](https://tentacles666.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/django-hierarchical-tags-with-taggit-and-tree/comment-page-1/#comment-364).

Which led me to the following code:

**Models**

```
class Taxonomy (TagBase, MP_Node):
    node_order_by = ['name']

class TaggedPost (ItemBase):
    content_object = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    tag = models.ForeignKey('Taxonomy', related_name='tags')

class Post(ItemBase):
    tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedPost, blank=True)
```

**Admin**

```
admin.site.register(Taxonomy, TreeAdmin)
```

Problem is when I go to admin to add the Taxonomies I get the following fields:

- Name
- Slug
- Path
- Depth
- Numchild

The last two **are not meant** to be input by hand, so says the [documentation of tree beard.](http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mp_tree.html)

> Do not change the values of path, depth or numchild directly: use one of the included methods instead. Consider these values read-only.

I went ahead and tried to input them myself, for the curiosity/stupidity, and the tree broke. So I had to use this hack to fix it:

```
f = Taxonomy.objects.all()
from django.db.models import QuerySet
QuerySet.delete(f)
```

Kudos to user “jrief” for [the hack](https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard/issues/69).

Another problem is the fact I can no longer access my **Post** model via admin. I get the following error:

**FieldDoesNotExist at /admin/main/post
Post has no attribute 'content_object'**

Keep in mind this is my first Django project and app. Appreciate any ideas you might have or a good django app for taxonomies, or an idea as of how to implement the taxonomies I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the app [Django Category](https://github.com/praekelt/django-category) and it's been brilliant. Just follow easy-as-pie instructions (barely any steps!) and everything works as expected.